# Rotate 2D matrix clockwise by 90 degree using array list only

Tags: java, list, matrix

Encountered this problem on hackerrank ,

Please guide on how to rotate a 2D array clockwise by 90 degree using `ArrayList` only?

Here is my code below:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> rotate(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int n) {
    
    int N=n;
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            matrix.get(i).get(j);
    }
    temp.add(matrix);  
    return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return the matrix passed as a parameter, right? That would mean you could create a new list of lists and then add the values accordingly. Rotation basically swaps columns and rows so depending on whether the first dimension is rows or columns you basically read the values from the same column or row and add then to the _new array list_ which you in turn add to the _new list_ that represents the entire matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it **in place**

```java
public static List<List<Integer>> rotate(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int n) {
    assert matrix.size() == n;

    /*
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
    */
    matrix.forEach(row -> {
        assert row.size() == n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            swap(row, i, row, n - 1 - i);
    });

    /*
        3,2,1
        6,5,4
        9,8,7
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            List<Integer> row1 = matrix.get(i - j);
            List<Integer> row2 = matrix.get(n - 1 - j);
            swap(row1, j, row2, n - 1 - i + j);
        }
    }

    /*
        7,4,1
        8,5,2
        9,6,3
    */
    return matrix;
}

private static void swap(List<Integer> one, int i, List<Integer> two, int j) {
    int tmp = one.get(i);
    one.set(i, two.get(j));
    two.set(j, tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if according to the requirements of this challenge you're expected to return a newly created nested list, then you can prepopulate it and then manipulate with it as if it's a nested array.

The key point you need to understand in order to solve this problem - is how in indices are getting changed during rotation of element. And the best way to visualize this is to draw this process on a paper.

If you'll do that, you'll be able to observe that while rotating elements of a square matrix clockwise that:

- a **row** becomes a **column**

```
row -> column // i -> j   in the code
```

- a new **column** index becomes equal to the matrix size `n` minus `1` minus previous **row** index

```
j -> (n - 1) - i
```

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> rotate(List<List<Integer>> matrix, int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = getMatrix(n);
    
    // i -> j & j -> (n - 1) - i
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int next = matrix.get(i).get(j);
            result.get(j).set((n - 1) - i, next);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

public static List<List<Integer>> getMatrix(int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> rotatedList = rotate(List.of(
        List.of(1, 2, 3),
        List.of(4, 5, 6),
        List.of(7, 8, 9)
    ), 3);
    
    rotatedList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[7, 4, 1]
[8, 5, 2]
[9, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static <T> List<List<T>> rotate(List<List<T>> matrix) {
    final int rows = matrix.size(), cols = matrix.get(0).size();
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>(cols);
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
        List<T> newRow = new ArrayList<>(rows);
        for (int r = rows - 1; r >= 0 ; --r)
            newRow.add(matrix.get(r).get(c));
        result.add(newRow);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = List.of(
    List.of(1,2,3),
    List.of(4,5,6));
List<List<Integer>> result = rotate(matrix);
for (List<Integer> row : result)
    System.out.println(row);
```

output:

```
[4, 1]
[5, 2]
[6, 3]
```